# from . import _mklinit ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: numpy, dllimport

I want to import NumPy in pycharm to practice on arrays but am getting this error message and the code i created is...

```
from Numpy import

arr = linspace(0, 16, 16)
print(arr)

E:\Anaconda\python.exe "C:/Users/Kenny T Mule Jnr/Desktop/try3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kenny T Mule Jnr/Desktop/try3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy import *
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: also have this problem. New job, corporate machine, installed Python 3.7.2, Anaconda (3.7.4), VS Code. The latter is where I am seeing this error, when using the Anaconda version of python as the interpreter (don't have numpy on the base Python install). Anaconda/Spyder was working 2 days ago but is now refusing to run (since installing OpenSSL).

Answer (score 7):

Try reinstall numpy:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

It solved the same problem in my case.

Comment: It worked great. In my case it was solved using pip install numpy --upgrade

Comment: This solved it for me as well using conda.  i.e. I just upgraded numpy using "conda install -c conda-forge numpy"

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these solutions worked in my case. There must exist a different cause I gather.

Comment: My particular message is
```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5820\1655018078.py in <module>
----> 1 import mkl

C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\user-package\lib\site-packages\mkl\__init__.py in <module>
     47 
     48 with RTLD_for_MKL():
---> 49     from . import _mklinit
     50 
     51 del RTLD_for_MKL

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

i.e. I import `mkl` directly.

Comment: And eventually I have solved it by using this piece of code: https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service/pull/27/files